# JSON (in SOAP UI- testing WSO2 services)

Tags: json, wso2, soapui

I tried giving a string value 'abccccc' in date field to test the functionality of the Date. It gave a error 500 exception. Shouldn't that be a 400 validation exception?

```
{
  "id": "rr56",
  "name":"reeta",
  "date": "abccccc"
}
```

Comment: What is the sequence that causes the failure?

Comment: In general invalid input should be handled by the application but as your code is unknown the fault could be also there. So please edit your question to include more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what validation is built into your service and where it is done. Without knowing more details of the implementation, a `400` would typically mean the request was malformed or too big or something like that. A `500` suggests the server-side implementation has choked when trying to parse `abccccc` as a date and thrown an exception, which has percolated back up the stack to what you see.